# Householder vs Gram–Schmidt Orthogonalization. Which should I use?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When should I use them, and how the relation of speed and precision changes?

Which are the advantages, and disadvantages of them?

Comment: Did you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization? there is a short advantage/disadvantage discussion there.

Comment: Thank you. But they don't write about the spped. I'm looking for a site, where this metods are compared by their relation of speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an $m\times n$ matrix,
[G. Stewart](http://books.google.fr/books?id=wqRARX3MXxQC&lpg=PP1&dq=matrix%20algorithms&hl=cs&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that both the Householder and Gram-Schmidt cost $mn^2-n^2/3$ floating point additions and multiplications.

The orthogonal factor computed by the Householder factorization is generally [more accurate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770882/why-is-householder-computationally-more-stable-than-modified-gram-schmidt/771271#771271) than that of the (modified) Gram-Schmidt unless the GS is implemented with reorthogonalization. On the other hand, GS gives the orthogonal factor directly, while Householder provides it in a factored form (essentially as a product of elementary reflections).

The loss of orthogonality does not need to be a problem for the modified GS, e.g., when solving least squares problem, a careful implementation (without reorthogonalization) can give the solution with the same accuracy as the Householder variant.

Also, GS is easier to implement and computationally more efficient in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, just one question. On which page can I read about Householder and Gram-Schmidt cost ?

Comment: In the book I've linked.

Comment: Oh if you mean on which page in the book, there are two sections related to Householder and GS in the chapter on the QR factorization, look there, it cannot be missed:)