# Why are Householder reflectors used in numerical linear algebra if the outer product isn't stable?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

The Householder reflector $H = I - 2vv^T$ contains an outer product with $v$, which is not backwards stable. Why are Householder reflectors still used -- wouldn't that lack of stability cause an issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770882/why-is-householder-computationally-more-stable-than-modified-gram-schmidt

Comment: @CyclotomicField not exactly: I'm curious about Householder reflector usage in general, not specific to the QR decomp. But I found another source that answers my question; I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $vv^T$ is an outer product which is not numerically backwards stable. But for any vector $b$, we can compute $Hb$ with

$$Hb = (I - 2vv^T)b = b - 2(v^Tb)v$$

and since most uses of Householder reflectors will involve matrix-vector products, the issue of the outer product is sidestepped.

Source: [1](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Elekheng/courses/302/notes10.pdf)